# generated signed apk crash when Release mode but in debug mode works perfectly

Tags: android, apk, react-native, version

> Blockquote

I have get apk with generated signed release mode, but app crash.but apk with debug apk is not crash.this is my react-native version is "react-native": "^0.62.2" and ext { buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3" minSdkVersion = 16 compileSdkVersion = 28 targetSdkVersion = 28 } this is my android/app/build.gradle

```
signingConfigs {
     debug {
        storeFile file('debug.keystore')
        storePassword 'android'
        keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
        keyPassword 'android'
     } } 
   buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
        // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    } }
```